# Is there a way for a variable to be assigned to the output of a print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python, and I was wondering if I could assign the output of a print function to a variable (so not `a = print('b')`, but something like `a = (the print output of printing b)`). I couldn't find much on my own.

```
#I have a list of variables assigned to text
thelist = ('abdf')
h = print(*thelist, sep=" ", end=" ")
j = str(print(*thelist, sep=" ", end=" "))

print(j)
```

Here's the closest I have right now.

Comment: Please be aware that fiddling with a print statement until the results look right and then "saving" the output to a variable is not considered normal practice and would be rejected in a homework exercise or code review. You would instead be expected to format a string correctly using Python's many convenient functions for this. They can easily mimic what `print` does.

Answer (score 1):

`print` does not expose the string it constructs from its arguments. You need to do that explicitly:

```
j = ' '.join(thelist) + ' '
```

That is,

```
print(*args, sep=x, end=y)
```

can be thought of as shorthand for

```
t = x.join(args) + y
print(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function's output to something file-like by specifying a `file=` keyword argument, such as a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) variable:

```
from io import StringIO

a, b, d, f = 1, 2, 'foo', 42
var_list = a, b, d, f

buffer = StringIO()

print(*var_list, sep=" ", end=" ", file=buffer)
print(buffer.getvalue())  # -> 1 2 foo 42
```

You could also do the same thing with the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) function as show below. It might be the better choice if you were going to do make multiple separate calls to `print` within the block.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

a, b, d, f = 1, 2, 'foo', 42
var_list = a, b, d, f

buffer = StringIO()

with redirect_stdout(buffer):
    print(*var_list, sep=" ", end=" ")

print(buffer.getvalue())  # -> 1 2 foo 42
```